# Problem with dynamic memory allocation in a helper function, in a header file

Tags: c, cs50

*Those who are familiar with CS50 Filter problem shall skip the first paragraph*

While trying to write code for [blur](https://youtu.be/dxNO-hCjT0w?list=PLhQjrBD2T382OwvMbZuaMGtD9wZkhnhYj) function of [CS50 Filter problem](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/), in which I have to implement only the filter, rest part is pre-written by CS50 staff (so don't ask me to *use this instead of that*, I cannot change anything except the code of function.).

To make a blurred image, I tried to copy `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));`. First statically, in which I had to run a nested loop to make it a copy of original image. And it worked.

But next when I tried using `calloc` and just copying the pointer instead, `image = temp;` the results were different. and This is the only thing I changed.

If [heap memory is not cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567981/does-memory-allocated-in-a-function-still-stay-allocated-after-the-function-retu) like stack, what may have went wrong?

NOTE: All these functions are stored in a different file, not the same.

Does this make a difference?

---

Static:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
            RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
                }
            }
            int i, j, k, l, prev_row, prev_col, next_col, next_row, c;
            float sumRed, sumGreen, sumBlue;
            
            for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                prev_row = i == 0 ? i : i - 1;
                next_row = i == height - 1 ? i : i + 1;
        
                for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    prev_col = j == 0 ? j : j - 1;
                    next_col = j == width - 1 ? j : j + 1;
                    
                    sumRed = 0;
                    sumGreen = 0;
                    sumBlue = 0;
                    c = 0;
                    
                    for (k = prev_row; k <= next_row; k++)
                    {
                        for (l = prev_col; l <= next_col; l++)
                        {
                            sumRed += temp[k][l].rgbtRed;
                            sumGreen += temp[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                            sumBlue += temp[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                            c++;
                        }
                    }
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / (float) c);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / (float) c);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / (float) c);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
:) blur correctly filters middle pixel
:) blur correctly filters pixel on edge
:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner
:) blur correctly filters 3x3 image
:) blur correctly filters 4x4 image
```

Dynamic:

```
RGBTRIPLE(*temp)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
int i, j, k, l, prev_row, prev_col, next_col, next_row, c;
float sumRed, sumGreen, sumBlue;

for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    prev_row = i == 0 ? i : i - 1;
    next_row = i == height - 1 ? i : i + 1;

    for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        prev_col = j == 0 ? j : j - 1;
        next_col = j == width - 1 ? j : j + 1;
        
        sumRed = 0;
        sumGreen = 0;
        sumBlue = 0;
        c = 0;
        
        for (k = prev_row; k <= next_row; k++)
        {
            for (l = prev_col; l <= next_col; l++)
            {
                sumRed += image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                sumGreen += image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                sumBlue += image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                c++;
            }
        }
        temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / (float) c);
        temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / (float) c);
        temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / (float) c);
    }
}
image = temp;
return;
```

OutPut:

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "120 140 150\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "40 50 60\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "10 20 30\n"
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "10 20 30\n40 5..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "10 20 30\n40 5..."
```

Comment: NO!!! Stack memory is _not_ cleared; heap memory allocated with `calloc` _is_ cleared. So the error is in your first try with stack allocated variables.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, This is different... Stack memory is not cleared after the call to function is completed?

Comment: If you turn warnings of your compiler on, you probably would get a warning about using uninitialized (stack) variables.

Comment: `image = temp;` What is `image`? Is it passed into the function? Can you please show that? If is passed in as a function parameter then it is a local variable and changing it does not change the caller's value.

Comment: I used that 2 dimensional struct array, initialize it to make a copy of original array.. While with calloc, I take data values from original, and set new values in  the new array, then I copy the pointer. So now you're saying, Memory by Calloc is disallocated, and stack variable are not cleared (though that would not matter because I only need local variable for computing average). Is that what you mean?

Comment: "Cleared" means "set to zero". "Released" means "available for others to use". Stack memory is not cleared but is released when the function returns.

Comment: @kaylum, Yes, it is declared in  a different .c file (the main file). And its declaration is the first code block in my code (calloc function). I simply copied that syntax to allocate for `temp`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, Oh, thanks for that information.

Comment: @kaylum, I added that in the question.

Comment: `image` is indeed passed in as a function parameter. So you cannot do `image = temp` as `image` is a local variable in that case and setting it does not change the caller's variable.

Comment: `image` looks like `, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])` and is passed _by value_.

Comment: But it is an array... and array's name is itself a pointer.

Comment: So? You can change the contents but you can't change the caller's pointer/array value itself.

Comment: An array is *not* a pointer. It can however *decay* to a pointer to its first element. And confusingly enough declaring an "array" function argument actually declares a pointer (i.e. as an argument `RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]` will really be `RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width]`).

Comment: And the problem is the standard "arguments are passed *by value*" problem beginners often have. When you call the function, the value of the argument is *copied* into the argument variable. Modifying the argument variable by assignment will only modify the local argument variable, not the original value used in the call. Either `return` the new value or do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks for the clarification. and Yes, I knew about passing by reference, I got confused with arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unfortunate that the prototype for the blur is not given, but is is probably something like
`void blur(RGBTRIPLE *image, int width, int height)`

It looks like you want to update the contents of image directly, instead of of creating a new one.

In that case your last statement `image = temp` will assign a new value to the local copy of the image pointer, but it will not affect the original value.

You want to copy the contents of temp, back to image with `memcpy`: `memcpy(image, temp, width*height*sizeof(RGBTRIPLE);`

After that you will need to `free` temp before returning, or you are left with a memory leak.

Comment: I added the prototype

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for pointers to arrays is a bit strange. You could pass a pointer to an array of height and width and allocate one array of height and width:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int RGBTRIPLE;
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE (**image)[height][width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE (*temp)[height][width] = calloc(1, sizeof(*temp));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            (*temp)[i][j] = i * 100 + j;
        }
    }
    *image = temp;
}

int main() {
    int height = 3;
    int width = 4;
    RGBTRIPLE (*arr)[height][width];
    blur(height, width, &arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, (*arr)[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

(You could use `arr[0][i][j]` instead of `(*arr)[i][j]` for easier typing and more confusion). You could also pass a pointer to an array of width and allocate height of arrays of width:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int RGBTRIPLE;
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE (**image)[width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE (*temp)[width] = calloc(height, sizeof(*temp));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            temp[i][j] = i * 100 + j;
        }
    }
    *image = temp;
}

int main() {
    int height = 3;
    int width = 4;
    RGBTRIPLE (*arr)[width];
    blur(height, width, &arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

**But** overall if you are just learning the language and you do not have any specific requirement to use a pointer to VLA, I would strongly advise to just use a pointer to a pointer. Don't be a [3 star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) and use a structure or return value to pass the result. Such code will be clear and understandable to any programmer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int RGBTRIPLE;
RGBTRIPLE **blur(int height, int width) {
    RGBTRIPLE **temp = calloc(height, sizeof(*temp));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        temp[i] = calloc(width, sizeof(*temp[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            temp[i][j] = i * 100 + j;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    int height = 3;
    int width = 4;
    RGBTRIPLE **arr = blur(height, width);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

In real code I would require to rather make `RGBTRIPLE` a more opaque type and write element accessor so that it can check out-of-bounds accesses and make the design a lot more object oriented, where the `RGBTRIPLE` is the object we are working on. Something along:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef int RGBTRIPLE;

struct rgbtriple_s {
    RGBTRIPLE **vals;
    size_t height;
    size_t width;
};

int rgbtriple_blur(struct rgbtriple_s *t, size_t height, size_t width) {
    RGBTRIPLE **temp = calloc(height, sizeof(*temp));
    // ERROR CHECKING!
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        temp[i] = calloc(width, sizeof(*temp[i]));
        // ERROR CHECKING!
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            temp[i][j] = i * 100 + j;
        }
    }

    t->vals = temp;
    t->height = height;
    t->width = width;

    return 0;
}

/// Get reference to.
int *rgbtriple_getr(struct rgbtriple_s *t, size_t x, size_t y) {
    assert(x < t->height);
    assert(y < t->width);
    return &t->vals[x][y];
}

int rgbtriple_get(struct rgbtriple_s *t, size_t x, size_t y) {
    return *rgbtriple_getr(t, x, y);
}


void rgbtriple_free(struct rgbtriple_s *t) {
    if (t->vals == NULL) return;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t->height; ++i) {
        free(t->vals[i]);
    }
    free(t->vals);
    t->vals = NULL;
}

int main() {
    const size_t height = 3;
    const size_t width = 4;
    struct rgbtriple_s data = {0};
    rgbtriple_blur(&data, height, width);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            printf("[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, rgbtriple_get(&data, i, j));
        }
    }
    rgbtriple_free(&data);
}
```

Note that in all above code error checking was not included, let's say for brevity, but really because I am too lazy to write it.

Comment: It'll take me some time to properly understand this answer. But thanks for the advice, it seems useful.